# Getting blank page on running localhost:3000

Tags: npm, gulp, ubuntu-14.04, mean-stack, mean.io

I have installed mean.io stack from http://learn.mean.io and everything installed successfully. When I tried to run `gulp` command to run the server I got this

```
Invoking gulp - development
[17:54:23] Using gulpfile ~/projects/mean/demo/myFirstApp/gulpfile.js
[17:54:23] Starting 'clean'...
[17:54:23] Finished 'clean' after 7.27 ms
[17:54:23] Starting 'default'...
[17:54:23] Starting 'coffee'...
[17:54:23] Finished 'coffee' after 11 ms
[17:54:23] Starting 'clean'...
[17:54:23] Starting 'less'...
[17:54:23] Starting 'sass'...
[17:54:23] Starting 'csslint'...
[17:54:23] Starting 'env:development'...
[17:54:23] Finished 'env:development' after 36 μs
[17:54:23] Starting 'devServe'...
[17:54:23] Finished 'devServe' after 40 ms
[17:54:23] Starting 'watch'...
[17:55:28] Finished 'watch' after 1.07 min
[17:55:28] Finished 'clean' after 1.07 min
[17:55:28] [nodemon] 1.8.1
[17:55:28] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[17:55:28] [nodemon] watching: *.*
[17:55:28] [nodemon] starting `node --debug server.js`
Debugger listening on port 5858
```

I am getting this error in the console.

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=mean&p1=Error%3A%20…angular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fv%3D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%3A20%3A449)
```

But when I am opening http://localhost:3000, I am getting a blank page. I am on Ubuntu 14.04.

[image: Blank page]

Any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: You've got errors on the console in Chrome, check those out (top right).

Comment: @dwjv I have updated the answer with console error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by running
    npm install
in the root directory of the app and then running
    gulp
again

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding "sudo" while installing "npm install --global gulp-cli" 
in the root directory.
like "sudo npm install --global gulp-cli".

and then run the command "gulp" otherwise there might be a permission issue.